# Use capacitor to turn on led when power is off

Tags: voltage, power

I have two LEDs in the circuit green LED turn on when the switch is on also capacitor is charged, Now I want to turn on the red LED by using capacitor when the switch goes off. Please help me, how I can do that. Thanks
[image]

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Are you saying you'd like it designed for you? Please edit your question and add your own work and own findings so far, ideas you have had, in plenty of detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: This circuit on its own is not much use. What are you really trying to make?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something along these lines. When SW1 is closed, C1 charges through D4 + D2 + R3 and D3 (green) is illuminated. R3 limits the current when SW1 is initially closed.

When SW1 is opened, D3 goes dark and D1 (red) is illuminated, and the current through it decreases (more or less) exponentially towards zero.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRRCwM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this simulation, the switch is opened at T = 1 second.

[image]